# Enable/Disable dropdown in a table based on first selection

Tags: aura

I have a table which contains 2 columns. Each of them has a dynamic select. On a button click new row is added every time.

```
<aura:attribute name="flag" type="boolean" default="true" />
<aura:iteration items="{!v.objectlist}" var="item" indexVar="index">
    <tr>
        <td >
            <select data-row-index="{!index}" onchange="{!c.enable2ndSelect}">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.somevalues}" var="v1" indexVar="key">
                        <option value="{!v1.value}">{!v1.label}</option>
                </aura:iteration>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td >
            <select data-row-index="{!index}" disabled="{!flag}>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.somevalues2}" var="v2" indexVar="key">
                        <option value="{!v2.value}">{!v2.label}</option>
                </aura:iteration>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

```
column1    column2
--------------------
DDRow10     DDRow20
DDRow11     DDRow21
DDRow12     DDRow22
```

Whenever I select a DDRow10, adjacent value DDRow20 should be enabled for selection. And other rows in column2 should stay disabled.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a flag for each row:

```
<select data-row-index="{!index}" disabled="{!item.disable2ndDropdown}>
```

Which you then set in `enable2ndSelect`:

```
enable2ndSelect: function(c,e,h) {
  let objectlist = c.get("v.objectlist");
  let index = parseInt(e.target.dataset.rowIndex);
  objectlist[index].disable2ndDropdown = e.target.selectedIndex <== 0;
  c.set("v.objectlist",objectlist);
}
```

If you only have one flag variable, you can only set one value. This is a fundamental aspect of programming.